# glui /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, linker, ld

I have downloaded the latest GLUI [source code](http://glui.sourceforge.net/#download) and now I am trying to compile it. When I do so, I get the following error:

```
g++ -O0 -Wall -pedantic -I./ -I./include -I/usr/X11R6/include -o bin/example1 example/example1.cpp  -L./lib -lglui -L/usr/X11R6/lib/libXdmcp.a -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXext -lX11 -lXi -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I did a `locate libXmu`, I get the following output:

```
> %:~/src/GLUI/src$ locate libXmu 
> /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6
> /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6.2.0
> /usr/lib/libXmuu.so.1
> /usr/lib/libXmuu.so.1.0.0
```

Do I get the error because I don't have a /usr/lib/libXmu.so? If this is the case, how can I make one? (I am not experienced with linking at all).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was actually one of the first ones here originally but the owner deleted it, it seems. I was able to solve the problem by creating a symbolic link to the latest version of the library (i.e. `/usr/lib/libXmu.so.6`) and compile the code successfully.

Comment: Thanks. For my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, I got it working with this command: 'sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 /usr/lib/libXmu.so'

Answer (score 7):

Linux distributions usually package the libraries needed for running programs separately from the files needed to build programs.

Look for packages named *-devel or *-dev.

I don't know which one you need in particular for this, but you can use apt-cache search to look for it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxmu-headers`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, if creating a symbolic link doesnt help, 
try the following:

1. Print your $PATH ("echo $PATH"), 
   and check if the library file you need is in one of those directories.
   Use "export PATH=/newly/added/path:$PATH" to add new directory to check.
2. Ive been including libevent, added "-levent" in the gcc command, and ld used file /usr/lib/libevent.so, so it looks like the "lib" prefix and extension are being added automatically by ld.

Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

As of Ubuntu 22.04 (and probably also in earlier versions), the package `libxmu6` provides the following files (one of which is a symlink):

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6.2.0
```

Whereas the package `libxmu-dev` provides the following file (which is actually a symlink):

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so
```

The `libXmu.so` symlink is what the linker will find, if it exists.

So to install the `libXmu.so` symlink via `apt`, run the below command (as mentioned by above by @Salami):

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
```